# SQL syntax for left join table 'unknown table'

Tags: sql, syntax, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

Display product ID, product name and the date of sale for all products sold.

```
SELECT products.prod_id AS Product
products.prod_name AS Product Name
FROM sales JOIN products WHERE sales.date_of_sale = sales.products;
```

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'products.prod_name AS Product Name FROM sales JOIN products WHERE sales.date_of_' at line 2

Comment: You are missing a comma, which is a typo.  Your `on` clause is also incorrect, but that has nothing to do with the question you asked.

Comment: You've missed a comma after column alias

Comment: is there any SQL/PHP pros i can talk to one to one, having a nightmare with this...

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to S/O. Your query is obviously off a bit.  Doing a "JOIN" identifies the relationship between your left table (listed first), and your right table (listed second).  This is typically going to be something of an A.ID = B.ID correlation.  Now, without having your actual table structures provided, I think what you are looking for is something like below using abbreviated "alias" to shorten and ease readability of query

```
select
      s.date_of_sale,
      p.prod_name
   from
      sales s
         join products p
            on s.prod_id = p.prod_id
   order by
      p.prod_name,
      s.date_of_sale desc
```

notice the guessing-context of the JOIN between the Sales (s alias) and Products (p alias) is based on the respective product ID from each side.

The field list of the selection is pulling the columns you want retrieved, hence the date of sale and the actual product name.

For grins, I also sorted the data so all the same product are sorted as primary, then for each product, I sorted by the most recent date sold first.  Just an extra to show how you could apply ordering the output of your results.